# Need loop to delete parts of file name

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, command, command-prompt

I have been using an image optimizer for my websites and when I do this, it gives me files with -compressor at the end of it.

```
input: filename.jpg   
output: filename-compressor.jpg
```

I need help in creating a batch file or a command script that I can just place these files into a folder and it will loop through all of these and change the names of these for me so that I don't have to go through them one by one.

Comment: Please specify the platform. Your tags are generic but Microsoft specifically calls their system "Command Prompt"

Comment: Windows platform because that is what a batch file works on.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p compressors
mv *-compressor.jpg compressors/
cd compressors    
for i in *-compressor.jpg; do j=${i%%\-compressor.jpg}.jpg; mv "$i" "$j"; done
```

Comment: tested the above edit on `nice pic-compressor.jpg` which gets moved to `nice pic.jpg`

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for a Windows solution, not 'nix.

Comment: Exactly, I was alluding to the missing quoting ;)

Comment: So...how do I insert this command? I am a little confused. Do I paste this into command prompt? Please give more detail of how to run this.

Comment: I see.  When I wrote the above answer, I assumed you were running a bash-like shell.  This will only work under Windows if you're using something like Cygwin, sorry.